# ODOO my header doesn't appears in my custom report

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have some trouble with my report header in odoo.
I can't make it appears correctly.
I've made a custom report here's the code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="report_timesheet">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                    <div class="page">
                        <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                           #SOMESTUFF 
                        </t>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

The thing is my header appears twice when I run this code, I've seen from standard module example that the line

```html
<t t-call="report.external_layout">
```

should be before

```html
<div class="page">
```

but when I do that the header doesn't appear at all. Does anyone have any idea about what's going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your report as following:

```xml
<template id="report_invoice_document">
<t t-call="report.external_layout">
    ....
</t>
</template>

<template id="report_invoice">
<t t-call="report.html_container">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
        <t t-call="account.report_invoice_document" t-lang="o.partner_id.lang"/>
    </t>
</t>
</template>
```